# Como puedo hacer dos count, cada uno de diferente tabla en una misma consulta de mongoDB?

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb

Estoy tratando de realizar dos count de diferentes tablas en una misma consulta de MongoDb, pero no se cual es la manera correcta, tengo algo pero solo me imprime uno de los dos count

```
console.log('totalRatingsMovies')
db.Ratings.find({}).count()
console.log('TotalMovies')
db.MovieInfo.find({}).count()
```

Comment: Ahi estas haciendo 2 consultas (que yo diría que es mas práctico que una sola consulta)... Que problema tienes con eso? Que te sale en consola?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, en MongoDB no existen "tablas", existe "colecciones", y segundo, en MongoDB las consultas se realizan sobre colecciones y no sobre toda la base de datos. Sin embargo, si deseas realizar una sola consulta para traer la cantidad de documentos de diferentes colecciones, podrías usar un [proceso de Agregación](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/).

Por ejemplo, podrías consultar la cantidad de documentos de la colección llamada `Ratings` usando un proceso de agregación y a su vez, en el mismo proceso contar la cantidad de documentos de la colección `MovieInfo`. El resultado sería un objeto con dos atributos cuyo valor representa la cantidad de elementos encontrados en cada colección.

```js
db.Ratings.aggregate([
  {
    $count: "TotalRatings"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "MovieInfo",
      pipeline: [
        {
          $count: "TotalMovieInfo"
        },
        
      ],
      as: "movies"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      TotalRatings: 1,
      TotalMovieInfo: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$movies.TotalMovieInfo",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Esto daría como resultado:

```js
[
  {
    "TotalMovieInfo": 4,
    "TotalRatings": 3
  }
]
```

Puedes probarlo en el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HDatDFgzvGa)

Sin embargo, un proceso de agregación siempre será más costoso que una consulta (*query*) usando `find`. Por lo cual, podrías hacer las 2 llamadas a la base de datos para obtener el mismo resultado de forma más eficiente (menos costosa) de la siguiente forma:

```js
const [totalRatings, totalMovies] = [
  db.Ratings.estimatedDocumentCount(),
  db.MovieInfo.estimatedDcoumentCount()
];
console.log(`totalRatings: ${totalRatings}, totalMovies: ${totalMovies}`);
```

Como puedes observar, se realizan 2 llamadas a cada colección para obtener el conteo estimado de documentos. Este método: [`estimatedDocumentCount`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount/) es un método que extrae la información de la metadata de la colección y es mucho más rápido que hacer: `db.collection.find({}).count()`. Adicionalmente, dispones del método [`countDocuments`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.countDocuments/#mongodb-method-db.collection.countDocuments) para contar documentos de una colección. Cada uno de ellos aplica según el caso de uso necesario. Sin embargo, usar `estimatedDocumentCount` es casi siempre lo más usual para obtener rápidamente la cantidad de documentos de una colección.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.